# why my query result is not showing any row

Tags: mysql, inner-join

i am working on a home project here i have to select multiple fields from two columns,i used INNER join to combine this two tables.I have a single column to match fields but i have to check two condition to select fields
My code for query is as follows

```
$frm_dt='2014-02-26';
  $to_d='2014-07-17';
      $sel_ser=mysql_query("SELECT m.counterSalesMasterId, m.date, m.cust_name, m.cust_doctor, d.ProductId, d.productBatchId, d.qty FROM sales_master as m INNER JOIN sales_details as d ON m.counterSalesMasterId=d.counterSalesMasterId WHERE (m.date BETWEEN $frm_dt AND $to_d) AND (d.sales_h1_flag='Y')")or die(mysql_error());    
        ECHO MYSQL_NUM_ROWS($sel_ser);
        while($res1=mysql_fetch_array($sel_ser))
        {
                       print_r($res1);

        }
```

i have to select those id between given dates and matching this ID in another table sales_detail, i have to check another two conditions which i have mentioned above

Plz help me as am very new to JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put single quotes around your dates.

```
$sel_ser=mysql_query("
    SELECT m.counterSalesMasterId, m.date, m.cust_name, m.cust_doctor, d.ProductId, d.productBatchId, d.qty 
    FROM sales_master as m 
        INNER JOIN sales_details as d ON m.counterSalesMasterId=d.counterSalesMasterId 
    WHERE (m.date BETWEEN '$frm_dt' AND '$to_d') AND (d.sales_h1_flag='Y')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Echo out the query if this still doesn't work and post the query with the dates.  Also, make sure that the date fields in the table are actually date fields and not string fields (varchar, etc).

Also, with `Inner Join`, if the table you are joining does not contain relevant rows matching the original `From` table, you will not get the rows from the original table either.